# How to give multiple examples for request body for POST request in Swagger2?

Tags: swagger-2.0

How we can define multiple examples for request object just like we define examples for response object as below.

```
 @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, response = Response.class, message = "Success", examples = @io.swagger.annotations.Example(
                    value = {
                            @ExampleProperty(value = "{'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2'}", mediaType = "application/json")
                    }))
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find much in swagger2, but i upgraded to openapi and then given examples as below

```
@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content = {
        @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, examples = @ExampleObject(value = "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\":\"value2\", \"key3\":\"value3\"}"))
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

enhancing "Abhinav manthri" answer using **"schema"** and using **"oneOf"** for multiple requests

```
@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content = {
            @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, schema = @Schema(oneOf = { MyReqBody1.class, MyReqBody2.class })) })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).